# Rendering paths wrapped in an ErrorBoundary with @reach/router

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

To make this short, I am trying to render some routes wrapped in ErrorBoundaries inside the Router but it does not correctly match the path supplied.

Here is a quick sandbox example that I set up to show what I am talking about.
If you check out the sandbox, and click on the `test` link, you can see that nothing renders even though the `ComponentWithoutErrors` has a `path` match on `/test`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-fire-bfehr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Your codesandbox have different issue

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting that if I play around with it, it actually updates the link I shared!
Should be sorted out now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens because `ComponentWithoutErrors` has a path of `test` and the ErrorBoundary surrounding it also has a path of `test`. So it matches `test/test`. We need to make the `ComponentWithoutErrors` component to have a path of `/`.

Here is the codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-zhukovsky-evw2b